# Change height of text in UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

How can I change the height of the text in a UIPickerView? Is it possible? I want to decrease the default height.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 2.2**

Implement pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) method in pickerView's delegate.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, scalePicker!.frame.size.width / 2, scalePicker!.frame.size.height / 7))
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Medium", size: 20)
        switch component {
        case 0:
            label.text = height_array[row] as? String
            label.textAlignment = .Center
        case 1:
            label.text = unit_Arr[row] as? String
            label.textAlignment = .Left
        default:
            break
        }

        return label
}
```